# Am I missing a step in order to process xpath expression in a wso2esb sequence?

Tags: xpath, sequence, wso2-esb

I've been messing with this for a few hours and I'm not sure what the issue is. Right now I'm just trying to log the result of an xpath expression of an XML file being passed to a sequence from a Proxy. So far nothing is being logged with my expression. I've changed the expression and namespace several different ways and I haven't been able to get the information to show up in the log. I can see the XML file being logged in it's entirety but not the data I'm trying to extract with xpath. When I run the xpath in a plugin I am able to pull the data just fine so I don't think it's an issue with the actual expression.

Can anyone push me in the right direction? I'm guessing it may be an issue with the XML format or namespaces but I'm not 100% sure.

Thank you.

Sequence

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="MySequence">
<log level="custom">
  <property name="sequence" value="MySequence"></property>
</log>
<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="filename" expression="get-property('transport', 'FILE_NAME')"></property>
<log level="custom">
  <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="show-name" expression="get-property('filename')"></property>
  <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="file-name" expression="get-property('targetfilename')"></property>
</log>
<log level="custom">
  <property xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset"
xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:z="RowsetSchema" 
name="sequenceExp" expression="count(//xml/rs:data/z:row)"></property>
</log>
<property xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" 
xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" 
name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" expression="fn:concat(get-
property('SYSTEM_DATE', 'yyMMddHHmmss'), '-', 
get-property('filename'))" 
    scope="transport"></property>
 <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"></property>
 <send>
  <endpoint name="FileEpr">
     <address uri="vfs:file:///var/process/rrout"></address>
  </endpoint>
 </send>
</sequence>
```

XML input data (starts with a schema, second child of `xml` element is the actual data)

```
<xml xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
xmlns:z='RowsetSchema'>
<s:schema id='RowsetSchema'>
    <s:elementType name='row' content='eltOnly'>
        <s:attributeType name='iQuizID' rs:number='1' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='int' dt:maxLength='4' rs:precision='10' rs:fixedlength='true' rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='iALSQuizNumber' rs:number='2' rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='int' dt:maxLength='4' rs:precision='10' rs:fixedlength='true' rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='iBookID' rs:number='3' rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='int' dt:maxLength='4' rs:precision='10' 
    rs:fixedlength='true' rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='vchBookType' rs:number='4' rs:nullable='true' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='10'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='vchQuizType' rs:number='5' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='2' 
        rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='vchQuizTypeDesc' rs:number='6' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='50' 
    rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='tiShowPointsInAR' rs:number='7' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='ui1' dt:maxLength='1' rs:precision='3' 
        rs:fixedlength='true' rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='tiAudioEnabled' rs:number='8' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='ui1' dt:maxLength='1' rs:precision='3' 
    rs:fixedlength='true' rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='tiAudioStatus' rs:number='9' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='ui1' dt:maxLength='1' rs:precision='3' 
    rs:fixedlength='true' rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='chTitlePrefix' rs:number='10' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='5' 
        rs:fixedlength='true' rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='vchBookTitle' rs:number='11' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='255' 
    rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='vchAuthorFirstName' rs:number='12' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='30' 
    rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='vchAuthorMiddleName' rs:number='13' 
    rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='30'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='vchAuthorLastName' rs:number='14' 
    rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='30'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='vchLanguageCode' rs:number='15' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='4' 
        rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='vchLanguage' rs:number='16' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='50' 
    rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='iFiction' rs:number='17' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='ui1' dt:maxLength='1' rs:precision='3' 
    rs:fixedlength='true' rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='vchFiction' rs:number='18' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='20' 
        rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='tiOutOfPrint' rs:number='19' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='ui1' dt:maxLength='1' rs:precision='3' 
    rs:fixedlength='true' rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='vchOutOfPrint' rs:number='20' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='20' 
        rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='iReadingLevel' rs:number='21' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='float' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='15' 
        rs:fixedlength='true' rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='vchInterestLevel' rs:number='22' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='10' 
        rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='iARPoints' rs:number='23' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='float' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='15' 
        rs:fixedlength='true' rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='flATOS' rs:number='24' rs:nullable='true' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='float' dt:maxLength='8' rs:precision='15' 
    rs:fixedlength='true'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='txBookSummary' rs:number='25' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' 
        dt:maxLength='2147483647' rs:long='true' rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='iWordCount' rs:number='26' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='int' dt:maxLength='4' rs:precision='10' 
        rs:fixedlength='true' rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='iNumberQuestions' rs:number='27' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='int' dt:maxLength='4' rs:precision='10' 
    rs:fixedlength='true' rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='iQuizStatus' rs:number='28' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='int' dt:maxLength='4' rs:precision='10' 
    rs:fixedlength='true' rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='dtOriginalApprovalDate' rs:number='29' 
    rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='dateTime' rs:dbtype='timestamp' 
        dt:maxLength='16' rs:scale='3' rs:precision='23' 
    rs:fixedlength='true'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='vchDifficultyLevel' rs:number='30' 
    rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='30'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='vchQuizISBN' rs:number='31' 
    rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='25'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='iContentID' rs:number='32' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='int' dt:maxLength='4' rs:precision='10' 
    rs:fixedlength='true' rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='tiRecordStatus' rs:number='33' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='ui1' dt:maxLength='1' rs:precision='3' 
    rs:fixedlength='true' rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='vchBookTitleContrived' rs:number='34' 
    rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' 
        dt:maxLength='1024'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='vchAuthorContrived' rs:number='35' 
    rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='500'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='vchCountry' rs:number='36' rs:nullable='true' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='10'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='iSponsor' rs:number='37' rs:nullable='true' 
    rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='int' dt:maxLength='4' rs:precision='10' 
        rs:fixedlength='true'/>
    </s:attributeType>
    <s:attributeType name='dtLastApprovalDate' rs:number='38' 
    rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true'>
        <s:datatype dt:type='dateTime' rs:dbtype='timestamp' 
        dt:maxLength='16' rs:scale='3' rs:precision='23' 
        rs:fixedlength='true'/>
     </s:attributeType>
    <s:extends type='rs:rowbase'/>
    </s:elementType>
</s:schema>
<rs:data>
<z:row iQuizID='18636' iALSQuizNumber='1' iBookID='3093' vchBookType=' ' 
vchQuizType='RP' vchQuizTypeDesc='Reading Practice'
     tiShowPointsInAR='1' tiAudioEnabled='0' tiAudioStatus='0' 
chTitlePrefix='     ' vchBookTitle='Adam of the Road'
     vchAuthorFirstName='Elizabeth' vchAuthorMiddleName='Janet' 
vchAuthorLastName='Gray' vchLanguageCode='EN' vchLanguage='English'
     iFiction='1' vchFiction='Fiction' tiOutOfPrint='0' 
vchOutOfPrint='In Print' iReadingLevel='6.5' vchInterestLevel='MG'
     iARPoints='9' flATOS='9' txBookSummary='This book describes the 
adventures of eleven-year-old Adam as he travels the open roads of 
thirteenth-century England searching for his missing father, a minstrel, 
and his stolen red spaniel, Nick.'
     iWordCount='57357' iNumberQuestions='10' iQuizStatus='1' 
dtOriginalApprovalDate='1996-04-10T00:00:00' vchDifficultyLevel=' '
     vchQuizISBN=' ' iContentID='118636' tiRecordStatus='1' 
vchCountry='US;CA' dtLastApprovalDate='2000-02-24T00:00:00'/>
<z:row iQuizID='18637' iALSQuizNumber='2' iBookID='3094' vchBookType=' ' 
vchQuizType='RP' vchQuizTypeDesc='Reading Practice'
     tiShowPointsInAR='1' tiAudioEnabled='0' tiAudioStatus='0' 
chTitlePrefix='     ' vchBookTitle='All-of-a-Kind Family'
     vchAuthorFirstName='Sydney' vchAuthorMiddleName='' 
vchAuthorLastName='Taylor' vchLanguageCode='EN' vchLanguage='English'
     iFiction='1' vchFiction='Fiction' tiOutOfPrint='0' 
vchOutOfPrint='In Print' iReadingLevel='4.9000000000000004'
     vchInterestLevel='MG' iARPoints='5' flATOS='5' txBookSummary='Five 
 girls have simple but happy times, with parents rich in kindness but 
 poor in money.'
     iWordCount='32006' iNumberQuestions='10' iQuizStatus='1' 
 dtOriginalApprovalDate='1996-04-10T00:00:00' vchDifficultyLevel=' '
     vchQuizISBN=' ' iContentID='118637' tiRecordStatus='1' 
  vchCountry='US;CA' dtLastApprovalDate='1996-09-19T00:00:00'/>
   </rs:data>
 </xml>
```

---------- Edit
You can get past this issue by changing the contentType in the proxy to 'application/xml'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> expression="count(//xml/rs:data/z:row)"
> ```

I can think of a few things why this can break:

1. You don't have the namespaces bound, so whatever executes your expression, your config file doesn't know these namespaces, unless it "magically" knows them.
2. The data "seen" by the tool is perhaps the actual `rs:Data`, and not the whole bunch that also includes the `xml` root node and the whole schema

Because I don't know the environment you work with, let's rewrite your expression in such a way that it is independent of the namespaces or the root element:

```
expression="count(/*//*[local-name(.) = 'data']/*[local-name(.) = 'row'])"
```

(added the `//` after the root node in case the structure is different than you showed) And if even that fails, consider using something even more ridiculous to make sure the XPath is even evaluated:

```
expression="concat('Hello world, count words: ', //@iWordCount[1])"
```

Since attributes are not in a namespace, this should output the first value of `iWordCount`. If it returns empty, you know that the document you think has the focus, does not have the focus. Here's a way to found out the first three element names:

```
expression="concat('Hello: ', name(/*[1]), name(/*/*[2]), name(/*/*/*[1])"
```

This should output: `"Hello: xml rs:data z:row"`

If not, it should at least point you to what data you are actually looking at.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Abel. I was messing with it some more today and I noticed the format of my XML changes by the time it gets to my sequence. I noticed it now includes a soap and text tag

'<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">&lt;xml xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
 xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
 xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
 xmlns:z='RowsetSchema'&gt;
'
Is there a reason the esb is changing the format of our input XML.?

Comment: @john, that's because it is used in a Web service call, which requires wrapping it in a valid SOAP envelop.

Comment: @john, the first expression I showed you will work, even if a SOAP envelop is wrapped around it. Did that solve your question? If so, you can mark this as the answer and/or upvote it.

Comment: it doesn't work. I've been trying all day and the only two elements I can pull are "soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" and "text". It doesn't grab any of the other elements at all. Not even when I run in the xpath plugin for firefox. I noticed my proxy was setting the contentType to text/plain. I tried changing it to text/xml and I get an error stating the format is wrong. It's expecting soap elements. I thought text/xml was for both plain xml and soap.

Comment: I tried changing the messageBuilder to "org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder" to try and treat the file as a pass through but it still wrapped the XML in soap elements. I'm using VFS to pull a flat xml file off a directory so I can process the XML elements.

Comment: @John: if the xpath has focus on the soap envelope, but the envelope contains your XML inside it, you should be able to get data from it. If you try my `concat()` examples above, do you at least get the static part of the concatenation? Can you then append a `count(//*[namespace-uri(.) != "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"])` to try to find whether your message is there to begin with?

Comment: Here is what comes back:

`expression="concat('Hello world, count words: ', //@iWordCount[1])" returns a blank`

`expression="concat('Hello: ', name(/*[1]), name(/*/*[1]), name(/*/*/*[2]), name(/*/*/*[1])) returns helloConcat = Hello: soapenv:http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/text`

`name(/*[1]) will return soapenv:http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`

`name(/*/*[1]) will return text`

this is all I am able to pull from the XML

`expression="count(//*[namespace-uri(.) != 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'])" returns 1.0`

Comment: @John, ok, getting closer. So there is only one element that is not in the SOAP namespace. Is is possible that the SOAP envelop does not contain your data at all? What does `local-name(//*[namespace-uri(.) != 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'])` return? That would be the first (and apparently only) non-SOAP element.

Comment: @John: another possibility is that your XML is escaped as text and not embedded as XML. You could see that in the envelop as either a `<[CDATA[` section, or escaped like `&lt;xml&gt;` etc.

Comment: that expression returned "text". I think you are correct and that it is being formatted as a text and not XML. I am seeing `&lt; and &gt;` for all tags after the `text` element. 

I can create another question for this since this has gotten kind of big, but how do I keep it from converting it to a text? is it because of the text/plain content type?  Is the SOAP format required for wso2esb?

Thank you for all of your help. I'll flag this as answered.

Comment: @john, wso2esb is an enterprise service bus. Just about every ESB out there uses SOAP for communication. It is possible to embed XML inside a SOAP message as XML, but that requires a certain configuration and it depends on what your XML is supposed to do. If it is essentially "filler", as in data that is dumped somewhere, you can just as well leave it as text, because the deserializer at the other end will see the unescaped text (i.e. xml). However, the downside is that it is hard to query it once it is inside a SOAP message, you first need to deserialize it.

Comment: @John and yes, I agree, it goes quite beyond the original question of the XPath expression ;). Unfortunately, XPath operates on XML, not on text. In XPath 3.0, it is possible to do a `parse-xml()` function call on such text, but I don't know if you can use XPath 3.0.